# htacess file to redirect azure defualt domain to main domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, azure

I have main domian **abc.com**  and azure created default domain **abc.cloudapp.net**

Now when i access abc.cluodapp.net it is working.

I want when someone access abc.cloudapp.net it should redirect to abc.com

here is my htacess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If Both the url are pointing to single location then use the following

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.old_site.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new_site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to custom domain or redirect the website’s request from abc.cloudapp.net to abc.com?

If you’d like to custom domain, you can write you CNAME (abc.com) into Azure portal.

Here is the [official guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/) about how to configure a custom domain name for an Azure cloud service.